# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgresql" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, alembic

Good evening, I have this problem that I can't solve, I've tried different ways without success.

I'm getting this error when I try to manually run the command inside the container: `alembic upgrade head`

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL=postgresql://admin:admin@postgresql:5432/medication_api
```

alembic.ini

```
[alembic]
script_location = alembic
output_encoding = utf-8
target_metadata = app.database.database.Base.metadata

sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://admin:admin@postgresql:5432/medication_api

[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

database.py:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL")

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

env.py:

```
from logging.config import fileConfig
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from alembic import context
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from app.database.database import Base
import os

load_dotenv()

config = context.config

database_url = os.getenv("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL")
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', database_url)
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
target_metadata = Base.metadata


def run_migrations_offline():
    context.configure(
        url=database_url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    engine = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    connection = engine.connect()
    context.configure(
        connection=connection,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
    )

    try:
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
    finally:
        connection.close()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

models.py:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date
from enum import Enum
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Date, Integer
from app.database.database import Base
from typing import Optional


class MedicationRequestStatus(str, Enum):
    """Enumeration representing the status of a MedicationRequest."""
    active = "active"
    completed = "completed"


class MedicationRequest(Base):
    """Represents a medication request."""
    __tablename__ = "medication_requests"

    id: int = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        doc="Unique identifier for the medication request."
    )
    patient_reference: str = Column(
        String,
        doc="Reference to the patient for whom the medication is requested."
    )
    clinician_reference: str = Column(
        String,
        doc="Reference to the clinician who prescribed the medication."
    )
    medication_reference: str = Column(
        String,
        doc="Reference to the medication being requested."
    )
    reason_text: str = Column(
        String,
        doc="Text describing the reason for the medication request."
    )
    prescribed_date: date = Column(
        Date,
        doc="Date when the medication was prescribed."
    )
    start_date: date = Column(
        Date,
        doc="Date when the medication should start."
    )
    end_date: Optional[date] = Column(
        Date,
        nullable=True,
        doc="Optional end date for the medication."
    )
    frequency: str = Column(
        String,
        doc="Frequency of medication dosage."
    )
    status: str = Column(
        String,
        doc="Current status of the medication request."
    )


class MedicationRequestIn(BaseModel):
    """Input model for creating or updating a medication request."""
    patient_reference: str
    clinician_reference: str
    medication_reference: str
    reason_text: str
    prescribed_date: date
    start_date: date
    frequency: str
    status: MedicationRequestStatus


class MedicationRequestOut(BaseModel):
    """Output model for returning a medication request."""
    id: int
    patient_reference: str
    clinician_reference: str
    medication_reference: str
    reason_text: str
    prescribed_date: date
    start_date: date
    end_date: Optional[date]
    frequency: str
    status: MedicationRequestStatus
```

Dockefile:

```
# Use the official Python image as base image
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional curl

# Copy only the requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install psycopg2-binary

# Install Alembic
RUN pip install alembic

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY . /app

# Expose the port that FastAPI runs on
EXPOSE 8000

# Initialize alembic
RUN rm -rf alembic && alembic init alembic

# Upgrade the database
CMD alembic upgrade head && uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.11"

services:
  medication_request_api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
    container_name: FastAPI_Medication

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: medication_api
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U admin -d medication_api"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "admin@gmail.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "admin"
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - medication_request_api

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I've already tried changing the database host to "localhost", "IPAddress" and it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me just connect alambic with postgresql?

Comment: The first thing to do is determine what the Postgres  server is listening on as detailed here [Connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) *listen_addresses*.  This will be found in the `postgresql.conf`  file.

Comment: I see your admin:admin@postgresql is trying to connect to the docker host "named" postgresql in your docker file... According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254343/why-cant-my-two-docker-containers-communicate-even-though-they-are-both-respond and https://www.tutorialworks.com/container-networking/ you need to a user defined network (i.e "named") or it won't do hostname resolution by default.  How are you using and finding the IPAddress option?  That can also work apparently.  Cheers!

Comment: You're running the `alembic` commands in the Dockerfile, which means it's trying to run it while building, when the database haven't even started yet. The way this is usually handled is to run the migration command as a `command` in the `docker-compose.yml` file (see e.g. [this tutorial](https://ahmed-nafies.medium.com/fastapi-with-sqlalchemy-postgresql-and-alembic-and-of-course-docker-f2b7411ee396)).